# How to Accomplish Adding Class to ONE item at a time (WayPoints)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I have this nice Waypoint.js scrolling list that when you scroll down and hit a certain percentage from the target (window), it changes the font style and adds an arrow to the list item.

Right now it’s adding the arrow to every item on the way down, and removing it from every item on the way up.

What I would like to know is if there’s a way to say “just one at a time" somehow that would allow the elements to change, but only one at a time (ie: One arrow is added (font awesome), and one font typeface changes at a time).

Essentially, "don’t add this class to more than one at a time, and only add it if you remove it from the one before it while scrolling down (I hope that makes sense!)

I tried to change it to toggleClass and remove class from .siblings(), which sort of works, but because these are multiple lists, it doesn't work. The last item in each ul keeps the arrow (I'll show an example below).

Here’s the website where you can see it working with the correct styles and arrows showing: If you scroll down this page to the OUR PROCESS section you’ll see what I’m working on :slight_smile:

https://stable.stable-demos.com/what-we-do/

Also note: I know I can make this work with siblings() except these lists must be broken up into different ul's because we need them to stack correctly together for mobile.

Thanks for your help!

```js
jQuery(function($){

// WHAT WE DO - ACTIVATE LIST AS SCROLL BY CHANGE FONT
 var continuousElements = document.getElementsByClassName("waypoint")
  for (var i = 0; i < continuousElements.length; i++) {
   new Waypoint({
   element: continuousElements[i],
   handler: function(direction) {

     if (direction === "down") {

      console.log(this.element.innerHTML + "down");
      $(this.element).addClass("gray active");
      $(this.element).removeClass("black");

     } else if (direction === "up") { 

      console.log(this.element.innerHTML + "up");
      $(this.element).addClass("black");
      $(this.element).removeClass("gray active");

     }
    }, offset: "50%"
   });

  }

}); // End jQuery
```

```css
/* What we do Highlight Text */
.black {
 color: black!important;
}
.gray {
 color: black!important;
}
.gray.active:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
 content: "\f061";
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.c-logo img {
 width: 80%;
}

.list-wrap div {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 8px 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 font-family: 'space_grotesksemibold';
}
.list-wrap div.active,
.list-wrap div:hover {
 color: black;
 font-family: 'gt_sectra_fineblack_italic';
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<div style="min-height: 2000px;">
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Think.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Research.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Involve.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Stragegize.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Plan.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Analyze.</div>
    </div> 
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Ideate.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Design.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Create.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Test.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Adapt.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Execute.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Report.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Learn.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Improve.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With siblings():

```js
jQuery(function($){

    // WHAT WE DO - ACTIVATE LIST AS SCROLL BY CHANGE FONT
     var continuousElements = document.getElementsByClassName("waypoint")
      for (var i = 0; i < continuousElements.length; i++) {
       new Waypoint({
       element: continuousElements[i],
       handler: function(direction) {

         if (direction === "down") {

          console.log(this.element.innerHTML + "down");
          $(this.element).addClass("gray active").siblings().removeClass('active');;
          $(this.element).removeClass("black");

         } else if (direction === "up") { 

          console.log(this.element.innerHTML + "up");
          $(this.element).addClass("black");
          $(this.element).removeClass("gray active");

         }
        }, offset: "50%"
       });

      }

    }); // End jQuery
```

```css
 /* What we do Highlight Text */

    .black {
     color: black!important;
    }
    .gray {
     color: black!important;
    }
    .gray.active:before {
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
     content: "\f061";
     padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .c-logo img {
     width: 80%;
    }

    .list-wrap div {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     padding: 8px 0;
     text-align: center;
     color: black;
     font-family: 'space_grotesksemibold';
    }
    .list-wrap div.active,
    .list-wrap div:hover {
     color: black;
     font-family: 'gt_sectra_fineblack_italic';
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<div style="min-height: 2000px;">
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Think.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Research.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Involve.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Stragegize.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Plan.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Analyze.</div>
    </div> 
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Ideate.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Design.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Create.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Test.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Adapt.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Execute.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="listWrap" class="list-wrap">
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Report.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Learn.</div>
     <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Improve.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code in the snippet is adding/removing the class one element at a time. Perhaps because they are so close together it's hard to see, but if you scroll slowly it work fine.

Comment: Yup, I think what I mean to say here is that I would like instead of list item 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 all having the .active class added as you scroll down, I would like only one list item to have the .active class at a time. 

For example, if you scroll down and list item 2 is .active, list item 1 .active class is removed. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

first thing you have multiple elements with same Id(listWrap) you can remove that, then add a class name to your parent div(.list-wrap-container).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<div style="min-height: 2000px;" class='list-wrap-container'>
    <div class="list-wrap">
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Think.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Research.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Involve.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-wrap">
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Stragegize.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Plan.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Analyze.</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="list-wrap">
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Ideate.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Design.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Create.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-wrap">
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Test.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Adapt.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Execute.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-wrap">
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Report.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Learn.</div>
        <div class="continuous-true waypoint">We Improve.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// js code

```
jQuery(function($){

    // WHAT WE DO - ACTIVATE LIST AS SCROLL BY CHANGE FONT
        var continuousElements = document.getElementsByClassName("waypoint")
            for (var i = 0; i < continuousElements.length; i++) {
                new Waypoint({
                element: continuousElements[i],
                handler: function(direction) {
                        // select the parent container
                        $(this.element).parent('.list-wrap-container').find('.gray.active').removeClass('gray active');

                        if (direction === "down") {

                            console.log(this.element.innerHTML + "down");
                            $(this.element).addClass("gray active").siblings().removeClass('active');;
                            $(this.element).removeClass("black");

                        } else if (direction === "up") { 

                            console.log(this.element.innerHTML + "up");
                            $(this.element).addClass("black");
                            $(this.element).removeClass("gray active");

                        }
                    }, offset: "50%"
                });

            }

    }); // End jQuery
```

// hope this helps

Comment: I really appreciate you taking a crack at it! This would definitely work, but for because the lists are broken up they seem to be only searching for siblings within the ul container. 

$(this.element).addClass("gray active").siblings().removeClass('active'); 

Only grabs the list items in that particular UL. Unless I'm doing something wrong here?  Best place to look at it (with all the WP Bakery Page Markup with your updated code is there) is https://stable.stable-demos.com/what-we-do/ - Again, THANK YOU for taking a shot at it though :)